# Creating 2D waveform for Cocos2d game

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, graphic-effects, particles

I'd like to have a Waveform in my iPhone game that I am developing using Cocos2d v2.0.

[image: Example Waveform]

That's the ideal wave I'd like to achieve. A simpler wave which I would still be happy with is this one.

[image: Example 2]

Some people suggested me to use ParticleEffects ands ParticleDesigners like [71squared](http://www.71squared.com/iphone-apps/particle-designer-ad/) but I am not sure that this is the right approach.

Brainstorming, I think that at the end a wave is a plot of some function, and at each frame translate the wave points that where from the origin apart (-x and +x) and computes new wave points for the origin.

Something like this:

```
for (duration of effect)
compute wave point intensity at origin and display it
and 
for each wave point before the center translate to -x and display it
and after the center translate to +x and display it
```

Let me know what you think and if you have any better solution. I was thinking to achieve the display point by colouring a particular pixel but I need to figure out how :)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the question also on the cocos2d-iphone forum and someone kindly replied. I thought I would share his answer to avoid duplicate effort:

[Answer](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/36353#post-173439)

I haven't yet tried them because I am struggling deciding what to learn first ES 1.0 vs ES 2.0 as I have just migrated my code to Cocos2d v2.0 and I don't fully understand all the implications, but judging Apple's AurioTouch example posted in the answer it looks promising.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to read as binary and parse from that.

for example: (Assuming you have a 8Bit wav file)

```
//Get your file
Load wav into buffer
for each 8 bit chunk convert to unsigned Integer
  add to array.

//Generate image
for each Integer scale it down to half your image size
  draw pixel wide line from center to top from scaled result.
  Draw a mirror image of that line directly below.
  X coord + 1

//Add prettiness.
Create gradient starting from center out like your image
Use generated image as mask to only expose the pixels you want to see.
```

That should give you the result you wanted, Unfortunatly I can't post code as I have little understanding of Objective C. Maybe pseudo helps tho :)

Comment: thanks for ur reply. I won't be using any wave files, I just wanted a wave effect for some animation purposes. Although your answer is still useful so +1. I'll leave the question open as I was hoping for some Cocos2d specific answer. Someone in a different forum pointed me out this tutorial http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/aurioTouch/Introduction/Intro.html and looks like I will have the next week busy learning that unless someone comes up with some additional useful learning material :)

Comment: Ah ok I think i misinterpreted "sound wave" what i believe you are actually looking for is a "Waveform" and this could be used minus the loading of the actual wav file and by randomly generating the numbers (Mayb add a thresh hold of change to ensure it doesn't vary too quickly)