# Cocos2d v2.0 and OpenGL 2.0/1.0: where to start

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I started developing my very first game 3 months ago using Cocos2d 2.0 for iPhone. I am now in the stage where I'd like to add some cool effects to the bullets and some special weapons (see my waveforms question [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/33451/creating-2d-waveform-for-cocos2d-game)). I got a good answer in the cocos2d-iphone forum (see [this one](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/36353#post-172950)).

Unfortunately I am a bit paralized now. I don't know if I will be overdoing by learning OpengGL 2.0 or if I should just stick ot the old 1.0. There is a good intro on various tutorial's written in Steffen Itterheims blog (see [this post](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/07/learnflash-great-opengl-es-20-tutorials-references/)).

I would like to add to my game:

- a blur effect to the bullets ([here](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/12/how-to-use-ccrendertexture-motion-blur-screenshots-drawing-sketches/) is a tutorial for OpenGL 1.0)
- a waveform (see above)
- some realistic water ripples (here is a nice [sample code](http://maniacdev.com/2011/12/example-how-to-make-realistic-water-ripples-with-cocos2d-very-impressive/))

So now, given that I don't want to overdo things but at the same time I want to achieve those effects, from where should I start? Should I discard the OpenGL 1.0 tutorials? OR should I use only OpenGL 1.0 code?

How can I avoid confusion? I mean, it seems that the compiler recognizes both, but that there are some conflictual calls in some circumnstances, I am fairly sure this has some explanation, is there some reference to this somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the "Shader Test" in the Cocos2d samples.

https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/blob/master-v2/tests/ShaderTest.m

This applies a Blur fragment shader to a CCTexture2D object from your CCSprite.

As for the other shaders you can find a bunch of running samples here:

http://www.iquilezles.org/apps/shadertoy/

This should get you started.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried looking at particle emitters?

http://particledesigner.71squared.com

Download that and check out the particle emitters on there, they do what you're after (blur effects and water ripples).

You add the files to your game like so:

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/7777

Add them to your resources folder and add them like that.

Comment: thank you, I tried 71squared and it doesn't seem to be able to achieve a waveform as I'd like.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I accepted the other one as more specific to my question but thanks anyway..